# Struggling with Python

Tags: python

I must answer this question in python but I'm not sure what i must do, this is the question:

> Your program should read in multiple lines of input from the user, stopping when the user enters a blank line. Each line will be a command from the user to the phone. Each command consists of a space-separated sequence of words.
>
> If the first word is Add, there will be two words following it: the name of the person and their phone number. If an Add command is encountered, your program should store this name to phone number mapping. Alternatively, if the first word is Call, there will be one word following it: the name of the person to call. In this case, if the phone knows the number for this person, your program should print out that it is calling that number, otherwise it should print out that it does not have a number for this person.

The program I have written is this:

```
contact = {}

**line = input('Command: ')
while line:
parts = line.split()
name = parts[0]
number = parts[1]
contact[name] = int(number)
line = input('Command: ')**
```

What more should I add or do to make this program work?

Comment: You should add _indentation_ to make it work. And remove the `**` if they are really in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish the different commands.

```
contact = {}

line = input('Command: ')
while line:
    parts = line.split()
    command = parts[0]
    if command == 'Add':
        contact[parts[1]] = parts[2]
    elif command == 'Call':
        pass
        # add the code to find the number and print it
    line = input('Command: ')**
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with you need to add a loop to keep asking the user for a command until they enter a blank line.

When writing an script which interacts with a user, it is also wise to think in terms of what the user could do wrong. The problem states a number of requirements, for example, if `Add` is entered, there should be two words following. If the user only entered one, what should you do?

Also what happens if the user enters a name that has not yet been entered?  Python dictionaries provide a `get()` method which handles this. It allows you to specify what needs to be returned when the requested key is not present. In this case, you can return "Unknown name".

The following shows what I mean:

```
line = ' '
contacts = {}

while line:
    line = input('Command: ')

    if line:
        words = line.split()

        if words[0] == 'Add':
            if len(words) == 3:
                contacts[words[1].lower()] = words[2]
            else:
                print("Badly formatted Add")

        if words[0] == 'Call':
            if len(words) == 2:
                print(contacts.get(words[1].lower(), "Unknown name"))
            else:
                print("Badly formatted Call")
```

By using the `.lower()` command on the entered name, it would then mean the user could do "Add Fred 1234 / Call fred" and it would still find a match.